# grant user roles in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, roles, database-administration

I want to know once you create a user role and add some privileges as:

```
CREATE ROLE usern NOT IDENTIFIED ;
GRANT SELECT ANY DICTIONARY TO usern ;
GRANT SELECT ON t90022.temptable TO usern ;
```

Can you edit the user role and just state the privilege as follows?

```
GRANT SELECT ON 90888.temptable2 TO usern ;
```

Will the user role be updated or do you need to drop and create the user role again?

PS: I don't have privileges to try this out. So please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Granting privileges in Oracle is cumulative. You do not have to re-grant privileges already granted, and in fact must revoke them explicitly to remove them.

Comment: Later if I want to give Insert privilege can I just say:                   GRANT INSERT ON 90888.temptable2 TO usern ; ?? Without re creating it??

Comment: @Sindu_ Yes, you are right! As DCookie said, it keeps appending to the existing privileges.